# SQL User-Defined Functions: Fetching TOP n records in a user-defined function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, user-defined-functions

How come the following doesn't work?

```
CREATE FUNCTION Test (@top integer)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
SELECT TOP @top * FROM SomeTable
GO
```

I just want to be able to be able to specify the number of results to be returned. [SQL Server 2000.]

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For MS SQL 2000, you can use:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Test (@top integer)

RETURNS TABLE

AS

SET ROWCOUNT @top

RETURN SELECT * FROM SomeTable
```

Answer (score 2):

Support for this was added to SQL Server 2005, but it's not available in 2000.  You'd have to use (shudder) dynamic sql or some other number trick instead.

Answer (score 1):

CREATE FUNCTION Test (@top integer)

RETURNS TABLE

AS

RETURN

SELECT TOP (@top)  * FROM SomeTable

GO

However without an ORDER BY clause it is not very meaningful (the order of the results is not guaranteed).

Answer (score 0):

Oops a variable TOP is not available in SQL Server 2000.  Nor is Dynamic SQL supported in any version.

Answer (score 0):

Jake, try setting the rowcount to your function parameter and then doing your select. I have not tried this, YMMV.

*From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259189(SQL.80).aspx*

Syntax

```
SET ROWCOUNT { number | @number_var }
Arguments

number | @number_var
```

Is the number (an integer) of rows to be processed before stopping the given query.

Comment: You can't used set rowcount in a user-defined function